# How can one translate “plug and play” and “energy ladder”?

Tags: traduction, informatique, terminologie

See this paragraph:

> with the goal of developing an **energy ladder** of **plug and play** energy products that separate energy generation/storage and distribution

What are French translations of "plug and play" and "energy ladder" in that context?

Comment: One question at a time please. And since we are not a translation service we appreciate OPs to say what they have found so far and why they do not think it's good enough for their purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that « prêt(e) à l'emploi » is a good translation of « plug and play », or you actually could use the original phrase in English inside of quotation marks, since it's something like an idiom.

As for « energy ladder », literal translation is « l'échelle énergétique », and [this page](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=energy+ladder) shows that it's obviously in use.

Comment: « Prêt à l'emploi » est en effet le [terme officiel](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=plug+and+play&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) proposé par la Commission générale de terminologie et de néologie.

Answer (score 3):

The translation of *energy ladder* is very simple it's : *échelle énergetique*.

For the translation of *plug and play* it becomes more complicated, I saw that everyone propose the term *prêt à l'emploi*, but this term is too generalist and can't be literally translated in a sentence. *Prêt à l'emploi* means you could use something directly, but doesn't really apply in computer science.

If you check the [wiki page](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug_and_Play) of *plug and play*, you will see that the terms *connecter et jouer* or *branche et utilise* are literal translations, but they are not used and don't even make sense in French.

So how to really translate it ?
Well you can't. You need to avoid this term in your sentence.

A good way to say that an peripheral object is *plug and play* in a sentence would be for example :

> Tu branches ton périphérique et il est automatiquement reconnu.

Which means :

> You plug your peripheral and it is automatically recognized.

Yes, there are terms that you can't translate…
Note that you can use directly the term *plug and play* in a French sentence if you're talking to someone that works in IT or is young enough to understand what it is.

Answer (score 0):

In France we use the term "plug and play". And "échelle énergétique" is a good translation for "energy ladder".

Comment: that's what I was thinking. But somebody told me it needed to be translated. so...

Answer (score -3):

Not serious answer: come on, we can do better than that. What about something that matches the original alliteration, such as "attache et pof ça marche".

Comment: Haha, yes in a oral conversation to a friend you could say : branche et ça marche.

Comment: Moderators, yes I'm quite sure my answer is not usable in a professional translation, and that something that a) reflects the alliteration b) is closer to "auto configuration on plugin" c) creative could be interesting. Leaving just the answer without the comment makes the answer incorrect and irrelevant.